# Snowflake Database : Loading JSON file from external stage with VALIDATION_MODE in COPY INTO statement

Tags: c#, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When loading **CSV**, there is an option to use VALIDATION_MODE with COPY INTO command.
This will give us a list of errors in all records in that csv.

```
COPY INTO "PUBLIC"."TableCSV"
FROM @my_csv_stage
FILES = ('TableCSV.csv')
VALIDATION_MODE = 'RETURN_ERRORS';
```

When loading **JSON**, all of these did not work :

```
COPY INTO "PUBLIC"."TableJSON1"
FROM @my_json_stage
FILES = ('TableJSON1.json')
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_SENSITIVE
VALIDATION_MODE = 'RETURN_ERRORS';
```

```
COPY INTO "PUBLIC"."TableJSON2"
FROM (
    SELECT $1:"col1" :: VARCHAR
          ,$1:"col2" :: VARCHAR
      FROM @my_json_stage 
  )
FILES = ('TableJSON2.json')
VALIDATION_MODE = 'RETURN_ERRORS';
```

```
COPY INTO "PUBLIC"."TableJSON3"
FROM (
    SELECT $1:"col1" :: VARCHAR
          ,$1:"col2" :: VARCHAR
      FROM @my_json_stage 
  )
FILES = ('TableJSON3.json');
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALIDATE("TableJSON3", job_id => '_last'));
```

I can see that the first example on [this snowflake page](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/validate.html) has the exact table that I want for JSON, but when I execute

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALIDATE("TableJSON3", job_id => '_last'));
```

it gives me this error :

```
SQL compilation error: JSON/XML/AVRO file format can produce one and only one column of type variant or object or array. Use CSV file format if you want to load more than one column.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue in the Snowflake. The engineering team is aware of the issue and they are actively working towards a fix. At this time there is no ETA on the fix timelines.